# TwitterKit 3.0 and TWTRLoginMethod

Tags: ios, twitter, twitterkit

So TwitterKit updated to 3.0 and `TWTRLoginMethod` / Twitter accounts registered in iOS settings seems to be gone. Are there any news about this, anywhere? It looks like the only option is to use web/Twitter app login, which is a clear step down in UX.

Update 1: Ok, there is a [changelog](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/changelog). It seems usage of accounts in iOS settings is not supported anymore. This is really really bad. We might have to consider to not use Twitter for login because of this.

**Update 2: So with iOS 11 Twitter/Facebook/etc accounts are gone from iOS settings app. That obviously makes the real reason behind this change.**

> 3.0.0: May 25, 2017 Added support for OAuth via the Twitter for iOS mobile app in -[Twitter loginWithCompletion:] and TWTRLogInButton
>   Update TWTRComposerViewController to handle full compose functionality
>   including image and video attachments Added result_type to
>   TWTRSearchTimelineDataSource. Removed boolean property topTweetsOnly
>   Removed TWTRLoginMethod in Twitter Added sending methods:
>   -[TWTRAPIClient sendTweetWithText:completion:] Changed TWTRComposer to present TWTRComposerViewController instead built-in iOS composer
>   Deprecated support for Card Removed TWTRComposerTheme Deprecated
>   TWTRComposer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter Kit no longer supports using system accounts directly.

The new Twitter App login will allow users to seamlessly use any session from their mobile Twitter app, and the SFSafariViewController based login will allow users to use logged-in sessions from Mobile Safari. These log in flows also allow users to view permissions that the app is requesting.

Comment: I finally got around to try this out again. For some reason I cannot get it to use the SFSafariViewController path, as far as I understand. Even having previously logged in to Twitter using Mobile Safari, it always asks me for user/pw when trying to login from my app. Using ` open func logIn(with viewController: UIViewController?, completion: @escaping TwitterCore.TWTRLogInCompletion)`

Comment: What's more, even after having logged in with the web view path once, then quit the app and try to login again, it has forgotten the logged in state and/or user/pass details.